# File sync and version control on LAN with a Drobo?

Tags: sync, file-management, version-control, drobo

I work in a office with another video producer and we have a networked Drobo. Currently we are using Backuplist+ to sync files to a common folder between our Mac Pro's. Works fine, but it's hard to know who's worked on what.

Is there a program out there that has version control and a GUI for a non-programmer like me?

I would be using it for video production, and not programming, like what Subversion systems are normally used for.

I've tried SparkleShare, but I can't get it to work with a local network - there could be a way to get that to work, I just don't know about it.